# System path for all users

Tags: windows-7

I want to send one link or path by which all my users can open the file or folder.
Scene is we have Skydrive & am sharing my docs with all users & all users are accessing that by sharepoint.
Now my requirement is i want to give one path (common path) to all user so that they can access the file.

Something like %windir%/system32 command.
command to access current user library then to specific folder...

Comment: It is %UserProfile% then / then required folder...this will open current user library then required folder..

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is called an Environmental Variable, not a System Path.

You can create one by doing the following:

1. Right click Computer, the click Properties. In the System window, click Advanced System Settings.
2. In Advanced System Settings, click the Advanced tab, then click Environmental Variables.
3. Under System Variables, click New. Create a variable by entering the name and the the path you want as a value.

   For instance, if I want to type `%foo%` to get to `D:\foo`, enter `foo` in "Variable name" and `D:\foo` in "Variable value".

Comment: Thank you very much for answering & correcting ...many thanks